# Expansion joins in 3m x 1.6m concrete retaining wall (with a brick wall ontop)

Tags: concrete, joints, cracks

[image]

I'm working on creating a concrete retaining wall; which is between two large rocks; and will support a wall, and roof on top of it. The whole building is a 3m x 3m shed. When the retaining wall is complete (I'm building it in sections) it will be an area of 3m x 1.6m

Would the retaining wall benefit from expansion joints? If yes; how do I create an expansion joint? Would creating a grove in the concrete wall be enough? What size would the grove be; and should it run horizontal or vertical?

As there are rocks on either side; I imagine the concrete can only expand "up" - does this risk cracking the wall that it will start supporting?

The concrete is supporting earth on the "outside"; so its temperature will be relatively stable.

Comment: two rocks or two pieces of the same rock?  should it be waterproof?

Comment: two rocks; I labeled them as stones in the picture.
Yes; I will try to make it waterproof.

Comment: No, concrete shrinks, unless you have a very long wall and is subjected to huge temperature variations. 3m is not a length that would cause significant problems but surface cracks. How to properly "keyed" into the rock is the most important/challenging task

Comment: Sounds good; thanks - happy to accept that as the answer if you move it down?